# jQuery MetaData "data" attribute doesn't validate

Tags: jquery, html, validation, metadata

Using the jquery metadata plugin, I have an element on my page that looks like this:

But, if I run this through the W3C Validator - I get an error saying "there is no attribute "data""

...have I missed anything (I realise data isn't a valid attribute, but this seems to be a 'bug' in the metadata plugin is it? - not one that's going to get fixed anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the metadata plugin, you put the data in the "class" string.

```
<div id='x' class='bigDiv purple spectacular {size: 200, weight: "19kg"}'>
```

Comment: Huh, interesting. Presumably this wouldn't affect any styles or anything?

Comment: well you separate the metadata stuff from your real classes - I'll type in an example

Comment: You can do multiple classes without any problem. You can't style the data between {} anyway.

Comment: South by Southwest Interactive conference (annual nerd fest in Austin)